# Infinite Sum Calculation

Tags: summation, factorial

How do we calculate this?

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n-1}{n!}$$

From my readings on previous posts here and through Google, I found that:

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}=e.$$

But then how do I manipulate that to help me find the answer? Through Wolfram Alpha, I know the answer is 1 but I don't know how to get to it. Thanks :)

Comment: This is a telescopic sum.

Comment: @Batominovski: True, but it can also be evaluated directly as $e-(e-1)=1$.

Comment: The identity $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty(x_{n-1}-x_n)=x_0$ only requires that $x_n\to0$, neither the convergence of the series $\sum\limits_{n} x_n$ nor that one knows the sum of the series  $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x_n$when it converges. Thus the "telescopic" approach is more powerful and simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break it up into two sums:

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{n-1}{n!}=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{n}{n!}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}.$$ Now note that $n/n!=1/(n-1)!.$

Comment: Thanks @Alex S. It works. The first one is $e$ but the second one is $e - 1$. So that adds up to $1$! 
Also, is there any other way to find this, other than using the known series we used above? I'm in a calc class and we didn't cover that in class, this came up in a worksheet. We should probably use things like convergence tests, ratio tests, integral tests, limits etc. Can we do this using any of that? Again, thanks :)

Comment: @soupynoodles One does not need to know the sums of the series to conclude, not even that they converge, see my comment on main. For example, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n(n+1)}=1$$ although $\sum\limits_{n\geqslant1}\frac1n$ diverges.

Comment: @Did Alright, thanks! But then can you give me a hint on how do you do it without knowing sums of the series or the identity on your comment on main?

Comment: The ratio test would work quite well to show that this series converges without knowing what its sum is.

Comment: Going back to the definitions, as usual: for every $N\geqslant1$, $$\sum_{n=1}^N(x_{n-1}-x_n)=x_0-x_N$$ hence, when $N\to\infty$, the RHS converges if and only if $x_N$ converges. Furthermore, if $x_N\to x_\infty$ when $N\to\infty$, then the sum of the series is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(x_{n-1}-x_n)=x_0-x_\infty.$$

Comment: Alright, I never learnt the definition @Did used though. It seems I need to know the sum of $1/n!$ to get to the answer. AlexS yes I can use the ratio test to say it converges, but then finding the sum is something else :) Would either of you agree with this?

Comment: @soupynoodles ?? What is your definition for the sum of the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$? For that matter, don't you have a definition of the *convergence* of a series?

Comment: Hi @Did, I do know that the sum of a convergent series is made when the partial sums of that series tends towards a certain value.

Comment: And *this is all you need to know* to solve the wide generalization of the exercise explained in my previous comment (and you just refuted your own "I never learnt the definition @Did used", and no, one does not "need to know the sum of 1/n! to get to the answer").

Comment: Hi @Did I'm a mere student who is new to all this, so I don't mean to frustrate you. I did not learn the thing that for every N greater than or equal to 1, and the rest of the stuff you did, but that's okay because this was the very very last question on the packet and that will probably not come up in finals. I really have not seen your way of writing it ever before, but it's something new to discover I guess. Thanks to both of you, and bye :)

Comment: No frustration but the feeling that you had not realized that you had all the notions you needed to solve this question and, more importantly to my eyes, to fully understand it (once again, yes, despite your statements of the contrary, you did learn everything there is to this). Of course, if your mental horizon is limited to some finals soon to come, such considerations are moot, I guess.

Comment: Sorry, I do not chat (and, since I already *emitted* as clearly as I could the point I wanted to make, its *reception* sort of does not concern me anymore).

Answer (score 2):

Note: $${n - 1 \over n!} = {n \over n!} - {1 \over n!} = {n \over n\times (n-1)!} - {1 \over n!} = {1 \over (n-1)!} - {1 \over n!}$$

Write this as telescoping and you should see that many terms cancel out.

So $$\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[{1 \over (n-1)!} - {1 \over n!}\right] &= (1 - 1) + \left(1 - {1 \over 2}\right) + \left({1 \over 2} - {1 \over 6}\right) + \left({1 \over 6} - {1 \over 24}\right) + \cdots \\ &=0 + 1 + \left(- {1 \over 2} + {1 \over 2}\right) + \left(-{1 \over 6} + {1 \over 6}\right) + \left(-{1 \over 24} + {1 \over 24}\right) + \cdots \\ & = 1 + 0 + 0 +\cdots \\ &= 1\end{align}$$

Comment: This method requires absolute convergence, which 1. holds in the present case, 2. should be mentioned, 3. is actually not necessary.