# Evaluate $\frac{1-S_{2011}}{1-S_{2012}}$ when $S_n=\sum_{r=1}^{n}{\frac{r}{(r+1)!}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

Suppose that,

$$S_n=\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{2}{3!}+\frac{3}{4!}+\ldots+\frac{n}{(n+1)!}$$

or more compactly, $S_n= \sum_{r=1}^{n}{\frac{r}{(r+1)!}}$. How can we find the value of $\frac{1-S_{2011}}{1-S_{2012}}$?

Comment: We have $S_n = \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{r+1-1}{(r+1)!} = \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{r!} - \sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{(r+1)!}$. Now try to shift the summation index in the first sum and the expression will simplify greatly.

Comment: @Winther Thank you, very valuable way of motivation to an answer.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1721312

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Notice:
>
> $$\text{S}(n)=\sum_{m=a}^{n}\frac{m}{(m+1)!}=\frac{1}{a!}-\frac{1}{(n+1)n!}$$

Now, when we can see that, when we set $a=1$:

$$\text{Z}=\frac{1-\text{S}(b)}{1-\text{S}(b+1)}=\frac{1-\left(\frac{1}{1!}-\frac{1}{(b+1)b!}\right)}{1-\left(\frac{1}{1!}-\frac{1}{(b+2)(b+1)!}\right)}=\frac{\frac{1}{(b+1)b!}}{\frac{1}{(b+2)(b+1)!}}=\frac{(b+2)(b+1)!}{(b+1)b!}=2+b$$

Now, in your example $b=2011$:

$$\text{Z}=\frac{(2011+2)(2011+1)!}{(2011+1)2011!}=2+2011=2013$$

Answer (score 1):

prove by induction that $$\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{r}{(r+1)!}=1-\frac{n+2}{(n+2)!}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{n}{(n+1)!}=\frac{(n+1)-1}{(n+1)!}=\frac{n+1}{(n+1)!}-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}=\frac{1}{n!}-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$

That leads,

$\frac{1}{2!}=\frac{1}{1!}-\frac{1}{2!}\\\frac{2}{3!}=\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}\\\frac{3}{4!}=\frac{1}{3!}-\frac{1}{4!}\\\ldots\\\frac{n-1}{n!}=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}-\frac{1}{(n)!}\\\frac{n}{(n+1)!}=\frac{1}{n!}-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$

So, $S_n$ will be equal to the summation of all these lines.

$S_n=\frac{1}{1!}-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$

---

$\frac{1-S_{2011}}{1-S_{2012}}=\frac{1-(\frac{1}{1!}-\frac{1}{(2011+1)!})}{1-(\frac{1}{1!}-\frac{1}{(2012+1)!})}=\frac {2013!}{2012!}=2013$

---

**Note:** I found the answer with the help of the comments of [Winther](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/147873/winther). 
Thank you.

> $S_n = \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{r+1-1}{(r+1)!} = \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{r!} -
>  \sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{(r+1)!}$